# Correlation between different individual and their scattershot using ggplot2 or ggpubr

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, ggpubr

A representation of my sample is :

```html
dat<-read.table(text=" AN1 AN2 AN3 ANM1 ANM2 ANM3
82 78 77 98 86 93
79 73 99 85 86 77
82 74 84 79 73 76
89 73 96 83 72 80
70 71 72 84 76 99
78 76 95 87 76 98
72 87 74 76 79 88
95 85 85 96 94 81
72 86 99 76 93 72
80 97 90 95 77 91
94 95 79 90 78 95
94 83 84 91 73 100
77 92 95 82 83 95
82 82 84 78 96 90
81 83 85 71 76 95
89 79 87 72 99 98
93 96 84 74 82 86
77 98 89 84 87 86
86 98 92 95 72 89
98 92 99 87 93 99",header=TRUE)
```

I want to make a correlation between AN1 and ANM1; AN2 and ANM2 and AN3 and ANM3 using a loop. I want to get "basic Plot" which is available [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/78-perfect-scatter-plots-with-correlation-and-marginal-histograms/). So I will get three scatter plots separately.

I have used the following codes, but it does not work:

```html
AN<-  dat[1:3]; ANM<- dat[4:6];
lapply(1:3, function(x) ggscatter(AN=[,x],ANM[,x]))
```

Comment: Please don't write "it doesn't work". Tell us what is going wrong, are you seeing an error message? Are the plots wrong? Are the plots not showing up?

Comment: remove the `=` from `AN=[,x]`?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error, since you define `AN` already in your question. But you'll need to use `ggscatter` correctly: `lapply(1:3, function(x) ggpubr::ggscatter(dat, x = names(AN)[x], y = names(ANM)[x]))`

Comment: You define `AN<-  dat[1:3]` in your question! It is working for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a `for` loop your code would look better. So, to purely reproduce your example, I would do something like this:

```
library(ggpubr)

dat<-read.table(text=" AN1  AN2 AN3 ANM1    ANM2    ANM3
82  78  77  98  86  93
79  73  99  85  86  77
82  74  84  79  73  76
89  73  96  83  72  80
70  71  72  84  76  99
78  76  95  87  76  98
72  87  74  76  79  88
95  85  85  96  94  81
72  86  99  76  93  72
80  97  90  95  77  91
94  95  79  90  78  95
94  83  84  91  73  100
77  92  95  82  83  95
82  82  84  78  96  90
81  83  85  71  76  95
89  79  87  72  99  98
93  96  84  74  82  86
77  98  89  84  87  86
86  98  92  95  72  89
98  92  99  87  93  99",header=TRUE)

for(i in 1:3){ 
  AN <- paste0("AN", i)
  ANM <- paste0("ANM", i)
  print(
        ggscatter(dat, x = AN, y = ANM)
      )

}
```

To try to create something similar with the **basic plots** from the link provided, I would change the `for` loop to something like:

```
for(i in 1:3){ 
  AN <- paste0("AN", i)
  ANM <- paste0("ANM", i)
  print(
      ggscatter(dat, x = AN, y = ANM, 
                  add = "reg.line", 
                  conf.int = TRUE, 
                  add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray")) + 
      stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.x = 3, label.y = 30) # Here label.x and label.y deform the plot, seems to be a case to tune them to your needs.
      )

}
```

Now, if you must use `lapply` I would try to create some abstraction by creating a function:

```
create_plot <- function(data, prefix_x, prefix_y, index) { 

  x_col <- paste0(prefix_x, index)
  y_col <- paste0(prefix_y, index)

  g <- ggscatter(data, x = x_col, y = y_col, 
                 add = "reg.line", 
                 conf.int = TRUE, 
                 add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray")) + 
    stat_cor(method = "pearson")

  return(g)

}

lapply(1:3, create_plot, data = dat, prefix_x = "AN", prefix_y = "ANM")
```